How to include require:timer in the 200 OK message after receiving an UPDATE message in freeswitch
FS ：Version 1.10.11-release  64bit
I need to reply to the IMS server when receiving an UPDATE message and add require:timer to the message.
I also used
<action application="set" data="sip_require_timer=true"/>,

but it didn't work，
I haven't found a solution. Please help me. Thank you.
SIP/2.0 200 OK
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 11.22.33.44:5060;branch=z9hG4bK7c344cd338adff0b
Record-Route: <sip:123.4.3.5:5060;transport=udp;lr;Hpt=9008_116;CxtId=3;TRC=ffffffff-ffffffff;X-HwB2bUaCookie=8210>
Call-ID: b31157ffb63616c6c00000002@11.22.33.44
From: <sip:81730012@11.22.33.44>;tag=5ed92dcd44555086
To: <sip:89108688@123.4.3.5>;tag=yu8daud8
CSeq: 21902 INVITE
Allow: ACK,BYE,CANCEL,INFO,INVITE,MESSAGE,NOTIFY,OPTIONS,PRACK,REFER,UPDATE
Contact: <sip:123.4.3.5:5060;transport=udp;Hpt=9008_16;CxtId=3;TRC=ffffffff-ffffffff>;audio;+g.3gpp.icsi-ref="urn%3Aurn-7%3A3gpp-service.ims.icsi.mmtel"
Require: timer
Supported: 100rel,path,replaces
User-Agent: iOS/17.5.1 iPhone
Session-Expires: 600;refresher=uac
P-Asserted-Identity: <sip:+8689108688@sbc.ims3gppnetwork.org>,<tel:+8689108688>
P-Access-Network-Info: 3GPP-E-UTRAN;utran-cell-id-3gpp=460005315c793c04;sbc-domain=jnpsbc2bhw.0531.013.sbc.123.com;ue-ip=[2409:813D:79:5ED4:83E:FBA0:315A:B52F];ue-port=50321
P-Charging-Vector: icid-value="51d58b52299c5b3ee560";term-ioi=sbc.123.com
Content-Length: 253
Content-Type: application/sdp
v=0
o=- 63092793 63092793 IN IP4 123.6.7.8


Require: timer
Supported: 100rel,path,replaces
User-Agent: iOS/17.5.1 iPhone
Session-Expires: 600;refresher=uac
